# NSManagedObject can't get attributes from NSAtomicStoreCacheNode

Tags: objective-c, core-data, attributes, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

I have one-to-one relationship between entity A and entity B (one sided), for example named bRel. I have subclasses of `NSAtomicStore` (MyStore) and `NSAtomicStoreCacheNode` (MyCacheNode). In the `load:` method of MyStore I create instances of MyCacheNode for entities A and B (aNode and bNode) and assign corresponding propertyCache dictionary for each one.  The propertyCache for aNode contains bNode for key `@"bRel"`.

The aManagedObject is created normally and has all the properties valid. But when aManagedObject accesses the bManagedObject through the `aManagedObject.bRel.someAttribute`, the bManagedObject remains fault. bManagedObject doesn't receive `awakeFromInsert` or `awakeFromFetch`. The bNode and bManagedObject share the same instance of `managedObjectID`. The bNode is alive when bManagedObject accesses someAttribute. When aManagedObject accesses its attributes, it goes through the `valueForKey:` of MyCacheNode. When bManagedObject does, we don't get there.

bManagedObject just never fires at all.

Can anyone suppose what should I check in this situation?

Comment: I'm having problems connecting relationships when using a custom NSAtomicStore, did you get anywhere with your issue?

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you access the relationship using mutable<Collection>ValueForKey ?

Answer (score 1):

yes. the problem may be that you have a Forward Declaration of aRel on your managed object.
Try importing it on the aManagedObject.h file. that way, you should be able to access it's attributes.

Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

From current perspective I think I've just didn't call `willAccessValueForKey:/didAccessValueForKey:` for synthesised properties, and that was irrelevant to customising store.
B was the synthesised property of A, AFAIR.